# How to set Monaco font in GNOME Terminal?

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I installed the Monaco font from [here](https://github.com/cstrap/monaco-font). The font is visible in Font Manager. I can also set the font in GVim.

However, if I try to set this font in GNOME Terminal, that is not possible. It is not listed in Edit > Profile Preferences > Font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem with 12.04. Remove your previously installed Monaco fonts. Install Monaco fonts available [here](https://gist.github.com/epegzz/1634235#file-monaco_linux-powerline-ttf) and try again.

It worked for me.